# data extraction from google chrome

Tags: excel, vba

I want to get table data from money control website. http://www.moneycontrol.com/financials/infosys/results/consolidated-quarterly-results/IT. I want to use google chrome to open this link and then click on previous years link and get that table too along with the table on that page. I need to click previous years as the url even after clicking previous years remains the same and I cannot directly navigate to it. It is easy with internet explorer but I cannot use it. If there is any other method other than having to click on the link please tell.

Answer (score 0):

Without using a third party library it is only possible to use the Internet Explorer object.

To automate Google Chrome you can try to use Selenium VBA. It's a COM library which creates a Windows COM wrapper for Selenium.
http://florentbr.github.io/SeleniumBasic/

In Google Chrome you have to install a plugin, which helps executing the VBA commands in Chrome.
Download page: http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

Comment: A first tutorial on how to use Selenium in VBA can be found here: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-automate-firefox-or-chrome-with-vba-and-selenium/